# How do I route in Fluentd by field content

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I wish to process (call a parser on) the contents of a log event via fluend.
These come different formats (json, apache2, nginx and bespoke regexp), sometime I may wish to skip any processing.

Events come from the **same source** (i.e. kubernetes logs) so the I cannot tag by source.
Currently I'm using vanilla fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch.

There doesn't appear to be a way of branching logic (there is only if there is no if else). So thus far I have only come across the following means of rewriting tag achieve this.

```
### Re-write the tag from log_format
<match **> 
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key kubernetes.container_name
    pattern /^(ingess-nginx)$/
    tag log.nginx
  </rule>
</match>

# Apache2 parser
<filter log.apache2>
  @type parser
  key_name log 
  reserve_data true
  inject_key_prefix log.
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type apache2
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</filter>

# Nginx parser
<filter log.nginx>
  @type parser
  key_name log 
  reserve_data true
  inject_key_prefix log.
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type nginx
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</filter>

<match **>
   @type elasticsearch
   @id out_es
   @log_level info
   include_tag_key true
...
```

This doesn't work. Logs that were arriving at Elastic Search are no longer doing so.
The issue appears to be within the first clause that attempts to re-write the tag,  although there are no errors and no indication as to what is going wrong. If I remove this paragraph event return to Elasticsearch, but obviously without the desire processing.

So how do I conditionally format (by way of the parser plugin) based on a field value?
Ideally I would prefer not to use container_name but an annotation which may not be present, is there a way of making the rewrite only occur is a particular field exists? and otherwise process as normal.

Comment: Are you using kubernetes?

Comment: did you manage to solve that? I'm having the same issue and would love any input.

Comment: Andrew Picking: I know this question is quite old, but it still comes up on Google. Your first match ** statement is the problem - this matches everything and no further match statements are being evaluated, the messages therefore never reach your elasticsearch output match.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [discussion](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/discussions/3645) with one possible solution to this use case. In this case it was important to implement a catch-all to allow messages to be passed on to the output. fujimotos also mentions an `out_copy` approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Attributes from kubernetes are nested (there is a paucity of documentation as to why) but consequently this requires a different [notation](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter#nested-attributes). Note the `key` line.

```
### Re-write the tag from log_format
<match **> 
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $.kubernetes.container_name
    pattern /^(ingess-nginx)$/
    tag log.nginx
  </rule>
</match>
```